# Splitting CSV before a dot

Tags: powershell

I would like to split the content of my hostname column and get the result before the dot.

```
Import-CSV "C:\AMP.csv" | Select-Object Hostname.split('.')[0], 'Internal IP' | export-csv -path "C:\result.csv"
```

can't seem to find the right syntax ERROR: Select-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have to use a **calculated property**:

```
Import-CSV "C:\AMP.csv" | Select-Object @{e={$_.Hostname.split('.')[0]}; l="HostName"}, 'Internal IP' | export-csv -path "C:\result.csv"
```